# Why does Invoke-RestMethod not send Credentials with UseDefaultCredential switch?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm using PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod` and want to send through the credentials of the currently logged in user. So I'm using the `-UseDefaultCredential` switch:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $serverUrl -UseDefaultCredential -ContentType "application/xml" -Body '<tags count="1"><tag name="testTag" /></tags>' -Method Put -Verbose
```

But I keep getting a 401 Unauthorised response.

When I create a `PSCredentials` object and pass that, it works.

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Credential 'someusername'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $serverUrl -Credential $creds -ContentType "application/xml" -Body '<tags count="1"><tag name="testTag" /></tags>' -Method Put -Verbose
```

Looking at Fiddler I can see both usages get an initial 401 but the option with `-Credential` sends a follow-up request with an `Authorization` header.

Why isn't `-UseDefaultCredential` working? What else can I look at to investigate this issue?

For reference this is sending request to the TeamCity REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Some web servers requires GET before POST. 
I presume it could be the same with PUT, you could try:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $serverUrl -UseDefaultCredential -SessionVariable s -Method Get
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $serverUrl -WebSession $s -ContentType "application/xml" -Body '<tags count="1"><tag name="testTag" /></tags>' -Method Put -Verbose
```